# How to pass to Frida a .ts file which depends on another .ts

Tags: frida

I have following `.ts` files

core.ts

```
interface Signature {
  args: string[];
  ret?: string;
}

const subject = 'hook'
const now = () => (new Date()).getTime()
const readable = (type: string, arg: NativePointer) => (type === 'char *' ? arg.readUtf8String() : arg)

export function hook(mod: string | null, symbol: string, signature: Signature) {
  const p = Module.findExportByName(mod, symbol)
  if (!p) throw new Error(`Function ${mod || 'global'}!${symbol} not found`)
  const range = Process.findRangeByAddress(p)
  if (!range?.protection.includes('x')) throw new Error('Invalid symbol, expected a function but received a data pointer')
  const id = p.toString()

  const lib = mod || Process.getModuleByAddress(p)!.name
  const listener = Interceptor.attach(p, {
    onEnter(args) {
      const time = now()
      const pretty = signature.args.map((type, i) => readable(type, args[i]))
      const backtrace = Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE)
        .map(DebugSymbol.fromAddress).filter(e => e.name)
      
      this.backtrace = backtrace
      send({
        subject,
        event: 'call',
        args: pretty,
        lib,
        symbol,
        backtrace,
        time
      })
    },
    onLeave(retVal) {
      if (!signature.ret) return
      const time = now()
      const ret = readable(signature.ret, retVal)

      send({
        subject,
        event: 'return',
        lib,
        symbol,
        time,
        backtrace: this.backtrace,
        ret
      })
    }
  })

  return listener
}
```

sql-hooks.ts

```
// import { hook } from './core'
const { hook } = require('./core.ts')

ObjC.schedule(ObjC.mainQueue, function () {
  enable()
});

function enable() {
  console.log('enabled')
  hook('libsqlite3.dylib', 'sqlite3_open', { args: ['char *', 'int'], ret: 'int' })
  hook('libsqlite3.dylib', 'sqlite3_prepare_v2', { args: ['pointer', 'char *', 'int', 'pointer', 'pointer'] })
  hook('libsqlite3.dylib', 'sqlite3_bind_int', { args: ['pointer', 'int', 'int'] })
  hook('libsqlite3.dylib', 'sqlite3_bind_null', { args: ['pointer', 'int'] })
  hook('libsqlite3.dylib', 'sqlite3_bind_text', { args: ['pointer', 'int', 'char *', 'int', 'pointer'] })
}
```

Then I used following command to connect these two files

```
frida-compile '/path/to/sql-hooks.ts' -o out.ts
```

Finally I used following command to actually use out.ts

```
frida -U -F -l '/path/to/out.ts'
```

But unfortunately I get this error

```
out.ts:1:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
out.ts:2:6 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'sql'.
out.ts:2:10 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'hooks'. Did you mean 'hook'?
out.ts:3:6 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'sql'.
out.ts:3:10 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'hooks'. Did you mean 'hook'?
out.ts:4:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
out.ts:5:11 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
out.ts:5:12 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
out.ts:5:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
out.ts:5:21 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
out.ts:5:48 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
out.ts:5:49 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
out.ts:5:105 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
out.ts:5:106 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
out.ts:5:130 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
out.ts:5:131 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
out.ts:5:144 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
out.ts:6:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into a `frida-compile` [example](https://github.com/oleavr/frida-agent-example) (from oleavr) and I found out I was doing a couple of things wrong. In particular I took a look at the [agent folder](https://github.com/oleavr/frida-agent-example/tree/main/agent) and at the [package.json](https://github.com/oleavr/frida-agent-example/blob/main/package.json) scripts region.

I'm going to mention two files: `sql-hooks.ts` (which is my `main.ts`) and `core.ts` (which is my `module.ts`); both of them are inside the same folder.

I changed first line of `sql-hooks.ts` from

```
const { hook } = require('./core.ts')
```

to

```
import { hook } from './core.js'
```

Notice I imported `core.ts` as a `.js`

Then I used following command to connect `sql-hooks.ts` and `core.ts`

```
frida-compile '/path/to/sql-hooks.ts' -o out.js
```

Notice output extension is `.js`

And that's it, everything's gonna work fine.